# deducing template specilization based on constructor arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm trying to provide a small class specialization when 2 provided types are similar and I have reached following code that works:

```
template<typename Fn, typename U, typename V>
class K {
    public:
    K(Fn f, U u, V v) : u_(u), v_(v) {
        std::cout << "2 args\n";
    }

    private:
    V v_;
    U u_;
};

template<typename Fn, typename U>
class K<Fn, U, U> {
    public:
    K(Fn f, U u) : u_(u) {
        std::cout << "1 args\n";
    }

    private:
    U u_;
};

void koo(int i, double d) {}
void moo(int i) {}

int main() {
    K(koo, 3, 5.6);
    K<decltype(moo), int, int>(moo, 3);
}
```

My only problem is that to select the specialization, I must provide `<decltype(moo), int, int>` manually or the specialization will not picked. I wonder if it is possible to pick this specialization based on single constructor argument so `K(moo,3);` works too. Any idea?

Comment: What C++ version are you using ? The answer you'll get will vary greatly from it

Comment: @Xatyrian I'm using c++-17, so that one will be enough :). But a c++-11 one will be great too for learning. :)

Comment: Add deduction guide: `template<class FN, class U> K(FN,U) -> K<FN,U,U>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple C++11-compatible solution would be to delegate the argument substitution to a helper function like `make_shared` for the `std::shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename Fn, typename U, typename V>
K<Fn, U, V> make_K(Fn f, U u, V v) {
  return K<Fn, U, V>(f, u, v);
}

template<typename Fn, typename U>
K<Fn, U, U> make_K(Fn f, U u) {
  return K<Fn, U, U>(f, u);
}
```

used as

```
auto k = make_K(koo, 3, 5.6);
auto m = make_K(moo, 3);
```

Comment: please add that deduction guide for c++-17 one as rafix mentioned too.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, provide deduction guide for [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```
template <typename Fn, typename U> K(Fn, U) -> K<Fn, U, U>;
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20fe3fb568a4794)